# Where is this place from Silicon Valley 3?

Tags: film-location, silicon-valley

Just wondering where is this restaurant really located in "Silicon Valley 3"?

Is this really in Silicon Valley or somewhere else? Does anybody know it by chance?

[image]

Comment: Silicon Valley 3? Season 3 or episode 3?

Comment: This seems like something that could be easily answered by typing "Joya restaurant" into Google....

Comment: It's in Season 3. Ha! I cannot access Google. And it's really good to hear from another person.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the Joya restaurant in Palo Alto, California. It's 20 minutes from Silicon Valley center. Both are part of San Fransisco Bay, but Palo Alto is considered the downtown business and store front area for Silicon Valley, which is mainly industrial parks and corporate headquarters.

[image]

You can see the University & Florence Street Signs in the front of your picture, and the stock Google picture.